# Android - Editbox Drawable left not padding correctly

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a editbox, in which I defined an `android:drawableLeft` property.

I am expecting to have the EditBox look something like this (from Instagram app):

[image]

Note that the image is properly centered, and the top/right/left/bottom padding of the image seems all the same. The text on the right is bounded by the size of the image (between the blue lines that I draw)

When I am trying to do the same thing, my EditText view look like this:

[image]

I also set the line number of this multiline edittext box to be three, but this did not help fix the box size. There is a big padding on the top/bottom of the image that I don't know where it comes from.  Here is my code:

Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_post_edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="@string/compose_card_hint"
        android:lines="3"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#999999" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Rounded corner drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#bbbbbb" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#2f6699" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

And also code to dynamically set the image:

```
Drawable img = this.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.sample_img );
    img.setBounds( 0, 0, 200, 200);

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_post_edittext);

    et.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

How I can re-adjust the layout to make it look the same as the Instagram one I showed above?

Thanks

Comment: Just separate the image from EditText, use ImageView & EditText and wrap it with relative layout.

Comment: got same issue. tried to use 9patch but it's useless

Comment: it's the `android:lines="3"` that causes the bottom and top padding. try setting it to 1 to see the difference. I don't think there's an easy workaround for that so I suggest that you follow the suggestion of @EvZ.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it.

1. Use a custom layout with an ImageView and TextView in a LinearLayout/Relative Layout. It will make your list items uniform irrespective of text and image size.
2. Using drawable with EditText in combination with lines is a bad idea. use drawableLeft or Right when you need to display image on edges with default gravity. Margin and Padding for drawables associated with EditText is a cumbersome task.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by changing `android:gravity="top|left"` to `android:gravity="center_vertical"`